# Can't change Windows 7 password

Tags: windows-7, command-line, password-recovery, system-repair-disc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I can’t change any system files from cmd](https://superuser.com/questions/542458/i-cant-change-any-system-files-from-cmd)

I forgot the Windows 7 password on my own computer, I used the trick described in [Resetting Your Forgotten Windows Password](http://www.howtogeek.com/96630/how-to-reset-your-forgotten-windows-password-the-easy-way/):

1. Boot from the Windows 7 repair ISO.
2. Execute:

   ```
   copy c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe c:\windows\system32\sethc.exe
   ```
3. Use the Sticky Keys feature of the log in screen (now the command prompt) to execute:

   ```
   net user Admin MyNewPassword
   ```

I kept the file there in case I ever forgot it again.

A client of mine asked if I could do the same for him, and he also has a PC with Windows 7 Home x86.

I followed the same steps as on my computer. The command of step 2 says it was successful, but when press <kbd>Shift</kbd> five times to trigger Sticky Keys, the regular message for `sethc.exe` opens up.

I tried entering the command of step 3 directly from the repair ISO. This claimed to be successful as well, but the password was not changed!

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you replacing tools?  What version of Windows 7 is your client using exactly.  Please clarify all details to only what must be shared.

Comment: Any chance your client has two different Windows partitions?

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend you to reset your password by this method, this is actually a method that cracker used to grant administrative rights. This is a vulnerability of windows that allow user to use a CMD with administrative rights before login.

If you forget to recover your `sethc.exe` with the original one, you are leaving a backdoor for everyone to access your computer with administrative rights without login. (If you can reset your password, everyone can do the same.)

If you want to reset your password, I would recommend you to use [Offline Windows Password & Registry Editor](http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/bootdisk.html) or [PC Login Now v2.0](http://www.pcloginnow.com/).Both of them are bootdisks, which you can burn to CD or install on a USB drive.

Offline Windows Password & Registry Editor is completely text based while PC Login Now v2.0 have a graphcal interface, which may be easier to use.

For more information, you can visit:

- **How To Reset a Windows 7 Password:**
- pcsupport.about.com/od/windows7/ht/reset-password-windows-7.htm
- **Offline NT Password & Registry Editor on About.com:**
- pcsupport.about.com/od/toolsofthetrade/gr/offlinentpwed.htm
- **PC Login Now v2.0 on About.com:**
- pcsupport.about.com/od/toolsofthetrade/gr/pcloginnow.htm

p.s. Sorry that I can't add more than two hyperlinks as I am a new user.

Comment: The offline windows password and registry editor is fairly well known. I'm less familiar with PC Login Now, and well, the site looks dodgy.